# Get files in PHP, which were created within a certain time range

Tags: php

The site I am managing is: http://edge.steyoyoke.com/ The site lets users download zip files, once they have paid for a subscription. They purchase the subscription from another site, and the user is manually created in edge.steyoyoke.com

The problem is, that I need the users to only be allowed access to the files created within one year of when they joined. So everything that was uploaded during the time the user is a paid member, they can download, but only during that time.

Right now each new user gets a data.txt file which looks something like like with the data filled in:

```
{"pass":"xxx","welcome":"Hello   [NAME]!","fullname":"xxx","email":"xxx","cookie":"e$nbe8bk#c6uh&a4sfjs29x7$y7vd7"}
```

When the user logs in, files from the user 'universal' are retrieved.

```
<?php $universal = new User( 'universal' );
if( $universal->exists() ) {
    $universal->get_files();
    if ( count( $universal->files ) ) {
        echo '<ul class="section">'; 
        foreach( $universal->files as $file )
            echo '<li><a href="file.php?universal=true&name='.urlencode($file).'">'.$file.'</a> <small>'.size($universal->path.$file).'</small></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }
} ?>
```

Thus far I've used this code to get the date that the user's data.txt file was created.

```
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator( 'users/nicholaskearney' );
foreach($iterator as $fileInfo){
    if($fileInfo->isFile()){
        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getCTime());
    }
    if($fileInfo->isDir()){
        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getMTime());
    }
}
```

So I can get when date when the user's data file was created, and I can get the current date, but I am stumped as to where to go from here.

I should say that I am new to PHP programming, and that this site was built by someone else, and I am now operating it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If I understood correctly, the date of the physical file on disk is the only way to track the subscription catalogue. That's far from being robust because there are many things that can reset the file system dates, from a file transfer to a backup restore. You should really be using a database to store the information explicitly, esp. if there's money involved.

Comment: Thank you @ÁlvaroGonzález for the reply. I've had the same idea, but I've got hardly any idea with databases. I suppose I need to get started on that first, because I read a post that seemed fairly simple to accomplish what I am trying to do, but using a database.